# Bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I'm in a bit of "trouble". I can't seem to put this dropdownmenu to work, I've read and read and can't find a solution. It just does nothing, doesn't dropdown. I would be glad if someone could lend me a little help.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quem Sou?</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exercício 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exercício 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
               <button class="btn nav-item dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   Dropdown
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exercício 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
Here's my header, since you all are referring for me to have the links

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ana Rodrigues</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: are you able to post a fiddle or a code pen with this? I will probably be able to help but I am too lazy to set it all up XD

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this website and you will find the problem:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/
Don't forget to add bootstrap in header or you might have forgotten to download the bootstrap files and then use your code.
Also you must be connected to the internet if you are using it in header.

Comment: I have the links and I am connected to the internet, I will have a look in that site

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the Bootstrap JS & jQuery into your project?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've got it in the header

Comment: And dropdown JS file? bootstrap-4.0.0/js/src/dropdown.js

Comment: Or your BS class

Comment: Removed many class of bootstrap or forgot to add them.
https://codepen.io/edgarMejia/pen/xaMNRQ

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include all the Javascript files needed to make all your bootstrap components work properly, just as @saeed said, on the link you gonna find the following:

" Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js. Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.

If you’re building our JavaScript from source, it requires util.js. "

Edit:

Did you make sure you were including the jquery JS file?

Comment: Yeah I've got that

Comment: Maybe you are not using the correct class for the dropdown? Just as the first example says on the bootstrap webpage?

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: I have tried to copy and paste the code from the first example and had the same result